# Undeclared identifiers in child contract

Tags: solidity

I am inheriting a contract from the OZ 1155 contract:

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol

It contains a function _safeTransferFrom that I have copied to my own contract. However, when compiling the contract, I get the following error:

```
DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
  --> project:/contracts/YieldToken.sol:97:50:
   |
97 |         _beforeTokenTransfer(operator, from, to, _asSingletonArray(id), _asSingletonArray(amount), data);
   |                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
  --> project:/contracts/YieldToken.sol:97:73:
   |
97 |         _beforeTokenTransfer(operator, from, to, _asSingletonArray(id), _asSingletonArray(amount), data);
   |                                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
  --> project:/contracts/YieldToken.sol:99:31:
   |
99 |         uint256 fromBalance = _balances[id][from];
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^

,DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
   --> project:/contracts/YieldToken.sol:102:13:
    |
102 |             _balances[id][from] = fromBalance - amount;
    |             ^^^^^^^^^

,DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
   --> project:/contracts/YieldToken.sol:104:9:
    |
104 |         _balances[id][to] += amount;
    |         ^^^^^^^^^

,DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
   --> project:/contracts/YieldToken.sol:108:9:
    |
108 |         _doSafeTransferAcceptanceCheck(opertor, from, to, id, amount, data);
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


Compilation failed. See above.
```

I get a bunch of undeclared identifiers. However, the 1155 contract that I'm inheriting from does contain those functions and those variables. Why is it showing undeclared identifier and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

functions `_asSingletonArray` and `_doSafeTransferAcceptanceCheck` are private so you can't call them by inheriting!

Also `_balances` is a private mapping, same goes for it too.